# HTTP/1.1 504 Connection refused

Tags: 12.10, proxy, tor, axel

I have a problem with internet in terminal, ubuntu 12.10. I try to download a file by [axel](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/precise/en/man1/axel.1.html) but i got an error:

```
HTTP/1.1 504 Connect to [URL]:80 failed: Connection refused
```

It's happen after I remove tor, how can i fix this?

Comment: I know have to change configure of something but i don't know where and how is it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Axel has a configuration file. This sits either in `$HOME/.axelrc` or in `/etc/axelrc`. In this file the proxy is configured. Look for a line starting with `http_proxy`. The line probably reads `http_proxy = http://127.0.0.1:8118`. Remove  it or place a `#` in front of the line. Now axel 'forgets' about the proxy and uses a direct connection.

If you find no such setting there might also be a shell variable called `http_proxy`. Just open a terminal and type `echo $http_proxy`. If you see a valid proxy, axel will also try to use it. Just `unset` the variable and axel will also use a direct connection.